# Templating lambda inside a map

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create a templated method that takes in an array and a lambda as a transformation function.

I want the API to look as follow:

```cpp
template <class T, class R>
void sort(std::vector<T>& array, std::function<R(const T&)> key);

// I want to call it
sort<SOME_CLASS,RETURN_TYPE>(some_array, [] (const SOME_CLASS& v) -> RETURN_TYPE { return v.property });
```

Maybe the approach I'm taking is not the ideal, I just want to know if its possible.

Ideally I would like the template to deduce the return type, so I can just do:

```cpp
sort(array, [] (const SOME_CLASS& v) -> RETURN_TYPE { return v.property });
```

I want to know whats the best approach for this problem, because this is not working.

I hope to get something similar to the python sort, https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: what is not working? Please include a [mcve] of your code in the question

Comment: btw you dont have to resort to a python example. You want something similar to [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: Btw if you write a template anyway it could be simpler and more efficient just to templatize whole functor, instead of wrapping it into `std::function`

Comment: use decltype(sort(array))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually in C++ you write template in more generic approach, for example `std::function` is usable when you have regular function that needs to accept a functor, template can use pretty much any functor (if it would bind of course):

```
template<typename Container,typename Functor>
void sort( Container &c, Functor f )
{
    std::sort( std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::move(f) );
}
```

And it will deduce data types:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 4, 3, 7, 1 };
    sort( v, []( int i1, int i2 ) { return i1 > i2; } );
    ...
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/GllSJZ)

If you can use C++20 you may want to add concept verification for data types, otherwise you may get some cryptic error messages if you use inappropriate ones.

Comment: This works, I replaced the std::sort , with my own implementation and it worked! I'll take a look at the concept verification. Thank you!